# nginx-rtmp video stream seeking functionality

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I am trying to make a video streaming service by using nginx-rtmp for reading stream and sending a dash/hls streaming media
[Used this link for live streaming media](https://www.nginx.com/blog/video-streaming-for-remote-learning-with-nginx/#installing-nginx-dependencies)

I used obs for sending the stream to nginx
But it is a live stream and user cant seek the stream

so, is there a way so that users cana actually seek it
Or is there a better way to stream video using dash/hls